# D3js, particular format for Time axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am not very fluent with D3, and have a need to make time axis labels of particular kind. I have timestamp data as X axis, and need axis to indicate **year, month, day** and then **hours**. If midnight is included, then again month and day (without year) if possible, or again year+month+day.

The event I depict on my graph lasts for day or several, so ticks are with semi-hourly interval. Yet as I said above, I need dates indication at start of graph and at all midnights.

So far I tried something like

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y %M %d %H"));
```

but with no apparent result (I still getting just hours).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could create a simple fiddle for it.

according to wiki, year, month, day + hours should be:

```
d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d %H")
```

[wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)